# In 2020, how to Email a SharePoint document as an attachment, not a link

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, attachments

There are lots of answers to the question 'Can I email a SharePoint document', but they often seem to suffer from two defects:

```
1. They assume the recipient has access to my SharePoint site
2. Many are years’ old and are obsolete.
```

I often need to send documents to an external contact, so they must be an attachment, not a link. Is this possible, as a one-step process? (I know I can download it from SharePoint, then upload it into Outlook.)

Comment: I tried and build a flow as per the instructions above and when I test it it was working. But now when I am trying it is giving me error "Parameter 'Attachment Content' cannot be null or empty." Did someone faced the same problem and found a solution? [![Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boU6d.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boU6d.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do that using Microsoft Flow. Please follow the below steps to develop the flow:

- Add a "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" trigger.
- Add a "Get file metadata" action, specify Site Address and File
  Identifier field set to Identifier dynamic content of the trigger.
- Add a "Get file content" action, specify Site Address and File
  Identifier field set to Identifier dynamic content of the trigger.
- Add a Condition, click "Edit in advanced mode", type the following
  formula:

  **@not(empty(body('Get_file_content')))**
- Within "If/yes" branch of Condition, add a "Send an email" action,
  Attachments Name field set to DisplayName dynamic content of "Get
  file metadata" action, Attachments Content field set to File Content
  dynamic content of "Get file content" action.

**Flow Image reference:**

[image: Send SharePoint document as attachments using Microsoft Flow]

**For details implementation refer to the below thread:**

[Send an email with attaching file from SharePoint library document](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-email-with-attaching-file-from-SharePoint-library-document/td-p/87682)

**Other 7 ways of sending SharePoint document in the email:**

[7 ways to attach SharePoint documents to an email](https://sharepointmaven.com/7-ways-to-attach-sharepoint-documents-to-an-email/)

Comment: How many of these steps are one-off set-up and how many need to be performed per email? Remember I asked for a one-step process. When following this, I got to a point where I had to accept the Ts and Cs, privacy statement and billing arrangements of Twilio, a third party. Lacking such authorisation, I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Here’re steps:

1.Add a new step: Get file content using path.
[image]
2.Add a new step: Send an email.
[image]
3.Result:
[image]

Update:

1.Add a step
[image]
2.Search the action named "Get file content using path".
[image]

Comment: I could not get this to work. I failed at the first step, when I could not find a 'Get file content using path'.

Comment: Update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to attach a SharePoint file if it is in your list of recent documents.

In Outlook Online, create a new message as normal. Click on `Attach`. The document may appear in the list of `Suggested Attachments`. If not, click on `Browse cloud locations`, then select the document from the list that appears.

In the box `How do you want to share this file`, click `Attach as a copy`. You may want to check `Remember my choice`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways (each with their pros and cons):

- Instruct users to download the files and then attach them in Outlook with a new email.

This involves multiple steps but requires no configuration and incurs no costs.

- Use OneDrive for Business client.

After synching the files of interest attach them in Outlook to a new email

- Use PowerAutomate.

Not very practical for organizations with lots of sites

- Use SharePoint apps ([list](https://collab365.com/10-best-sharepoint-email-management-software/)) that offer this capability.

Select one or more files in SharePoint, click "Mail items" to generate a new email with the selected files attached
example[image]